# Filter Solr query by field

Tags: search, solr, nosql, lucene

I've got a large set of records like this in my index, and what I'm trying to do is to find the objects by **SUB** property, for example if I want to filter by sub = "5 7 8 10 820" it should result in returning in objects  B and C, because they both have 5, 7, 8, 10 and 820 in their SUB property.

*To generalize object's sub should contain all of the values (5,7,8,10,820) passed in filter.*

Object A has only 5, 7 and 8. Therefore it doesn't satisfy the filter.

Object B has 5,7,8,10,820 in its sub property, therefore it satisfies the filter

as well as Object C does.

**How can I fix my query to achieve such behavior?**

This is my current query which returns what I think is all of the occurrences of the filter in objects properties:

```
q=*:*&rows=100&start=0&sort=id+asc&fq=%2Bsub:5+7+8+10+820

Object A: {
        "id":"ke131j-nan139-1239Mzf-sazr",
        "sub":"0 1 3 4 5 7 8"
         etc...
}

Object B: {
        "id":"ke131j-1239Mzf-nan139-sacr",
        "sub":"5 7 8 9 10 517 820 1121 1124"
         etc...
}

Object C: {
        "id":"nan139-1239Mzf-sazr-ke131j",
        "sub":"5 7 8 10 11 15 783 820 825 921 924"
         etc...
}
```

Comment: `q=sub:(5 AND 7 AND 8 AND 10 AND 820)`? (or `fq` instead of `q` if you don't need any scoring (together with `q=*:*`))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from the comment was helpful, q=sub:(5 AND 7 AND 8 AND 10 AND 820), worked